# Unable to open Spyder

Tags: python, terminal, pip, homebrew, spyder

I have installed spyder from source from its [main page:](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html#installing-or-running-directly-from-source)

Before this, I used brew to install some dependencies and pip3 as well for some anothers.

I was able to open spyder from terminal just typing "spyder" but after I quit the terminal an re opened again I am now unable to doing this. The last option is to use Anaconda but, am I going to need to delete all the previos packages I previously have installed? is there any chance I can keep using spyder without installing conda?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know anything about MACs, but is some error displaying while you're trying to run spyder from terminal?

Comment: The only thing that shows is: -bash: spyder3: command not found

Comment: You probably have to add it to the system path

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*)

> is there any chance I can keep using spyder without installing conda?

Yes, it is possible, but not our recommended nor the easiest method of installation.

As we mention in our [Releases page](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases), using `pip` to install Spyder is for experts or very knowledgeable programmers only. That's because due to time and resource constraints we are unable to support those installations.

This means that *any* installation problems faced when using `pip` (like the one you're posting here) are expected to be solved by the users themselves.